Chrome Extension error: Failed to execute 'writeText' on 'Clipboard': Document is not focused
I have created a Chrome Extension for myself to extract text from a given webpage's URL using regex.
The extraction works fine, the issue I am encountering is when I want to write the extracted text to the clipboard I get the error:
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'writeText' on 'Clipboard': Document is not focused.

My manifest.json is:
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Get Record Id",
    "description": "Copies the Salesforce Record Id from the URL",
    "version": "1.0",
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "scripting",
        "tabs",
        "clipboardWrite"
      ],
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
      },
    "action": {
      "default_icon": "hello_extensions.png"
    },
    "commands": {
        "_execute_action": {
          "suggested_key": {
            "default": "Ctrl+B",
            "mac": "Command+B"
          }
        }
      }
  }

and a MVP of my background.js:
function getTabId(tab){
    return tab.id;
}

chrome.action.onClicked.addListener((tab) => {
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
      target: {tabId: getTabId(tab)},
      func: copyRecordIdToClipboard,
      args: [tab]
    });
  });

  async function copyRecordIdToClipboard(tab){
    const url = await tab.url
    console.log(url)
    let recordId = "0067R00001xiHXYQA2";
    console.log("RecordId is: ", recordId);
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(recordId)
  }

The extension works fine in Chrome on my MacBook, but it is throwing this error when I use it in Chrome on my Windows computer.
I followed instructions on examples given here, and here which suggests using a setTimeout function, but no joy.
Any other suggestions will be much appreciated!
Thanks

Sounds like a bug in Chrome. Use document.execCommand('copy') instead as shown here.

Thanks @woxxom. I tested the extension locally and all seems to work. I want to add my own logic to return the excerpt from the URL. How to I get the URL retrieved. I tried modifying the chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(async () => {}); to chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(async (tab) => {});, but that didn't work. Do I need to retrieve the tab information some other way?

The example contains sendMessage where you can put your data e.g. extractSomething(tab.url)

@woxxom thanks - I got it working. I appreciate the help and effort
