How to focus document for navigator.clipboard.writeText to work?
Using Chrome, I try to access the clipboard via: Clipboard.writeText. I am on a https page, when I do:
const clipboardPermission = await navigator.permissions.query({name: "clipboard-write"});

The clipboardPermission.state will be granted.
Yet when I do afterwards:
await navigator.clipboard.writeText('some string');

I get the error:
"Failed to execute 'writeText' on 'Clipboard': Document is not focused."

How am I / the user supposed to focus the document? (In order to interact with clipboard, the user has to interact with the DOM, so I am confused where the issue stems from.)

For Chrome Extension, maybe duplicate:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78555143/chrome-extension-error-failed-to-execute-writetext-on-clipboard-document-i
